# IE background size not working

Tags: css, internet-explorer, background

I'm trying to make a background stretch the entire body (width only). This works only on Chrome,Opera and Firefox. How can I make this work on IE too? O_o

```
background-size:100%;
-moz-background-size: auto 100%;
-o-background-size: auto 100%;
```

Comment: Are you working in IE9? Else.. it's CSS3 markup. So no can do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since background-size is CSS3 specific your gonna have to use something like this for it to work in IE

set your html and body to

```
html {overflow-y:hidden}
body {overflow-y:auto}
```

wrap the image you want fullscreened with a div #page-background

```
#page-background {position:absolute; z-index:-1}
```

then put this in your html file

```
<div id="page-background">
  <img src="/path/to/your/image" width="100%" height="100%">
</div>
```

** you will have to use some sort of reset to remove the margins and paddings, something like this

```
html, body {height:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}
```

Comment: Yeah, I already read this. I thought there's a css-only solution :D. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 4):

I created [jquery.backgroundSize.js](https://github.com/louisremi/jquery.backgroundSize.js): a 1.5K jquery plugin that can be used as a IE8 fallback for "cover" and "contain" values. Have a look at the [demo](http://louisremi.github.com/jquery.backgroundSize.js/demo/).

Comment: Hi Louis, I have tried using your code but there is some unexplainable space on the bottom of the IE 8 browser. When I toggle open and close the inspect element console, it display perfectly find, full screen. But when the page is load, it is not full screen, there is some space on the bottom. Also, I noticed that when page load, the top of the image is being cut off, example displaying the bottom 9/10 of the image and the 1/10 on top is not displayed. After I toggle the inspect element console, it display 10/10 of the image. Is there a way to fixed it? Hope you understand what I am saying.

Answer (score 0):

background-size is not supported in IE for versions [under 9](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#lists). A cross browser solution is to use a jquery plugin like [fullscreenr](http://nanotux.com/blog/fullscreen/).

Comment: Ok, then I'll ignore IE8 users on this one :)) :D