# background-size:100% 100%; property not working in IE

Tags: css

What is the alternative CSS property for "background-size:100% 100%;" in Internet Explorer(IE)?

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806310/ie-background-size-not-working, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991623/make-background-size-work-in-ie, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885145/ie-8-background-size-fix

Answer (score 1):

Which version of IE? 
Microsoft Internet Explorer 9.0+ offers full support for the background-size property.
IE6, 7 and 8 will **not** support `background-size`
As far as I'm aware there is no CSS alternative for `background-size`.

Depending on what you're trying to do, you could have a `<div><img>` in your HTML and achieve the same result by absolute positioning the div and setting `img{width:;}` in your CSS...